# Asking user to input value between specific range recursively in JAVA?

Tags: java, recursion, stack, java.util.scanner, activation-record

I am writing a code in Java, where system will ask user to input integer between 1 and 10 (both Inclusive), and if the value is out of range, it should recursively ask the user to enter value again. And at the end I have to print the value which was within the range.
Here below is my code:

`import java.util.Scanner;
public class InputInteger {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Enter first Integer between 1 and 10 (both inclusive):");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num1 = isInRange(sc, sc.nextInt());

    System.out.println("Enter Second Integer between 1 and 10 (both inclusive):");
    int num2 = isInRange(sc, sc.nextInt());

    System.out.println("Num 1 is "+num1+"\nNum 2 is "+num2);    
    sc.close();
}

public static int isInRange(Scanner scanner, int num) {
    if(num<1 || num>10) {
        System.out.println("WRONG INPUT. PLease enter Integer between 1 and 10 (both inclusive):");
        num =scanner.nextInt();
        isInRange(scanner, num);

    }
    return num;
}
```

}`

This will be my output:
[image: Output Image]

The problem which I am facing is,when I am putting wrong values and ultimately when I put the right value, it will print the value which I entered at second time. Let's say I am putting 8 values which are out of range, and after that my 9th value is within range, so it will print the value which was entered at second time.

Comment: Have you stepped through your code with a debugger? Using a debugger and stepping through your code is the best answer to this question. Why is this question tagged with `[activation-record]`?

Comment: @JonnyHenly I have been debugging this by putting System.out.println(num) right before return statement in the method. And it was printing all the inputs inputted by the user except the very first input.
And this question has activation record tag, because when you call a method in Java, there will be an activation record created for that function, and this is stored in the memory in terms of stack.

Comment: Is it really important to do this recursively? Maybe you can find a better way to do this. One problem is, that even if a number is "out of range" it still is returned at the end of isInRange().

Comment: @GitPhilter Yeah I know it can be easily done with the loop, but I just want to know how this can be fixed and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Using `System.out.println(num)` will not be able to show you the values of each variable (along with a lot of other information) as you go through the recursion. A debugger will allow you to set breakpoints, step into and out of function/methods, view variable values, change variable values, etc. Take a serious look into using a debugger, it will save you so much time in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You missed a little detail:

```
public static int isInRange(Scanner scanner, int num) {
                if(num<1 || num>10) {
                    System.out.println("WRONG INPUT. PLease enter Integer between 1 and 10 (both inclusive):");
                    num = scanner.nextInt();
                    num = isInRange(scanner, num); // add "num = " at the beginning of the line
                }
                return num;
            }
```

isInRange() returns an integer that you forgot to set to num.

Comment: You could also use `num = isInRange(scanner, scanner.nextInt())` instead of assigning `num` before the recursive call. It is arguably less readable, but more compact.

Comment: @GitPhilter Thanks, it is fixed. Can you please give me a brief explanation, how it got fixed? Is this over ride all the values in the stack?

Comment: @ Jonny Hely Yeah, this is possible as well. My solution is kind of weird, because you assign a vaule to num in two consecutive lines, which looks weird.

Comment: @Parteek Singh Bedi your function isInRange returns the correct int with "return num" at the end, but you never used the returned value.